# Is there a way to distinguish between clients in bottle wsgi application code?

Tags: session, wsgi, bottle

I would like to know which http client is executing requests in my
bottle web application.

For example if a client makes an AJAX call from one browser tab
and another tab is making the same request, I would like to distinguish
between the two "user sessions" in my application code in subsequent
AJAX calls.

- I tried using `bottle.request.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"]` and `bottle.request.environ["REMOTE_PORT"]`, but as
  it is changing for every http request it doesn't really help ;
- I tried to use cookies, but cookies are shared between multiple html
  documents, and they need to have unique names
- My last resort is to pass a unique id from the client in every request,
  so I can distinguish between clients in my web application Python code ;
  however I would prefer a less obstrusive solution

Any advice ?